# is it possible to enable the app automatically when mac is powred on

Tags: swift, macos, authentication, launch

[image: []

I need help in launching the os x Application automatically when user sign in as shown in above figure enable tick mark using programatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it's quite simple, you just need to call this [function](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1501557-smloginitemsetenabled):

`SMLoginItemSetEnabled("com.your.app" as CFString, true)`

The problem is that your application cannot register its own app identifier (unfortunately), so to be able to register it you will have to make another 'igniter' application. You may find a nice explanation [here](https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187426/can-i-know-how-to-detect-the-screen-sharing-is-running-or-not-in-mac

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SMLoginItemSetEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1501557-smloginitemsetenabled?language=objc), please find below an copy an Objective-C method to enable auto-start I used in an old project :

```
- (IBAction)setAutoStart:(id)sender {

    // save the user preference:
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:[sender state] forKey:@"AutoStart"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    // enable or disable it:
    if ([sender state] == 1) { 
        // loginController.startAtLogin = YES;
        if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.yourproject", YES)) {
            NSLog(@"fail");
        }
    } else if ([sender state] == 0) { 
        //loginController.startAtLogin = NO;
        if (!SMLoginItemSetEnabled ((__bridge CFStringRef)@"com.yourproject", NO)) {
            NSLog(@"fail");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49187426/can-i-know-how-to-detect-the-screen-sharing-is-running-or-not-in-mac